# unable to connect the remote server with very simple httpWebRequest class app

Tags: visual-studio-2010, httpwebrequest, connect

I used visual2010 to write a simple app with httpWebRequest class. The very first time of running the app, it'd work but after some successes, it was stuck with warning 
**"unable to connect the remote server".** 
I have read a lot in net but not much clues could done, almost said because the anti virus soft or firewall cause the problem, but when i'd turn off both, it still does not work. I also reinstall visual2010 but the problem still

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Net;
using System.IO;

namespace new_httpWebRequest
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string result ="";
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://my-favor.net");
        // line code problem below:
        `HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();`
        var sr = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream() ?? System.IO.Stream.Null, Encoding.UTF8);
        result = sr.ReadToEnd();
        sr.Close();
        Console.Write(result);
        Console.ReadLine();

    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 5):

finally, i find the solution just by adding this line:

request.Proxy = null;

I don't know why it work, just do it by god bless.

Comment: We encountered this issue when trying to make WebRequest from a web application which had a default proxy in web.config. This helped into getting to the web.config and adjusting the proxy.