# access denied to a webservice, however I can browse to it

Tags: c#, web-services, iis, geonames

I am trying to access http://ws.geonames.org/countryInfo which I can browse to fine, however in my code I am getting access denied I am not sure why, I am testing the service by having the following code on page_load

```
XmlDocument xml = new XmlDocument();
xml.Load("http://ws.geonames.org/countryInfo");
```

I also just found out if I create an app and use IIS express the webservice returns data fine however running on IIS 7 is when the problem occurs.

Comment: works fine for me. Firewall issue?

Comment: yeah i thought of that as well.. turned the firewall off.. still got the same issue.

Comment: Is there an exception that occurs? (or more details of the explicit error)

Comment: error message says..
A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond 5.9.41.208:80 
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 
Source Error: 
        {
             XmlDocument xml = new XmlDocument();
            xml.Load("http://ws.geonames.org/countryInfo");

        }

Comment: strange that your error ommits the http part. But that doesnt seem to be the issue, because if you leave that out you would get path errors.

Comment: Any chance you need to use a proxy? See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13283228/unable-to-connect-the-remote-server-with-very-simple-httpwebrequest-class-app

Comment: i am using a proxy, and I am clearing the cache and obj folders.

Comment: xml.Load("ws.geonames.org/countryInfo"); } @chris Is this your correct stack trace details? Where is protocol http in here? or is it just a typo.

Comment: xml.Load("http://ws.geonames.org/countryInfo") is correct, the return error message strips the http off, and returns the IP address, though it works on IIS express, but not in IIS 7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[DotNetOpenAuth...CreatRequest breaks on server (Works on my machine ;-)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16237741/dotnetopenauth-creatrequest-breaks-on-server-works-on-my-machine)

basically it was the proxy, I changed the applicationpool identity to me and it went through he proxy fine. Why IIS express was getting through and not IIS 7.5 I am not sure.
 hope it helps.

Comment: Because IIS Express runs under your credentials. Explaining all those details (using a proxy that uses authentication, working in IIS Express but not in IIS) in your question would've helped solve it faster.

Comment: I did mention IIS Express and 7.5, but true enough on the proxy, but I didnt really know how it was set up.